# ssrs InStr, Right second occurrence

Tags: reporting-services

I have three files.

---

**Full_Item_Dev_01,
Item_Live_01,
Full_Item_Test_01**

---

I need them to be changed to Dev_01, Test_01, Live_01 inside the SSRS builder only, so I need to take text after the second _ occurrence from the right side, without _.

I can easily find an answer to that, if it was a left side, or even if Dev, live and test were the same char length, but it always changes on the left, and char length different as well..
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you mean you have string `Full_Item_Dev_01, Item_Live_01, Full_Item_Test_01` that you need to convert to `Dev_01, Test_01, Live_01` ? You mention files but I assume that this is not relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not written any VB for many years so this is probably not the most elegant solution, but it does work.

Add this custom code to the report

```
Public Function TrimWords(s as String)
        dim newWord as String
        dim newWords as String()
        dim f as integer

        dim words() as String
        words = s.Split(",")
        
        For f = 0 to words.length - 1
            dim parts() AS String 
            parts = words(f).Split("_")
            newWord = parts(parts.length - 2) & "_" & parts(parts.length - 1)
        
            ' resize the array 
            If newWords IsNot Nothing Then
                Array.Resize(newWords, newWords.Length + 1)
                newWords(newWords.Length - 1) = newWord
            Else
                ReDim newWords(0)
                newWords(0) = newWord
            End If
        
        next
    
    dim result as String
    
    result = String.Join(", ", newWords)
    return result
End Function
```

Then simple set your textbox expression to

```
=Code.TrimWords(Fields!filelist.Value)
```

Where `filelist` is the column name containing the string you want to convert.

I built a simple test report and here are the results, the original text is in the left column and the results of the expression is in the right column .

[image]